# Question about existence of special function

Tags: general-topology

Is there any orientation-preserving homeomorphism $g:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ s.t. $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n,g(g(x))=x$ that is not $g(x)=x$ or $g(x)=-x$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. For instance, take $f\colon\mathbb{R}^3\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ defined by $f(x,y,z)=(-x,-y,z)$.

Comment: Is there also an example when n=2?

Comment: @C.Park Yes. Take, for instance, $f(x,y)=(1-x,1-y)$.